Large stored procedure unit testing best practices / general methodologies
I have been creating a unit testing system for our SQL Server databases using the tSQLt framework. In the early stages of this process I have started creating some basic unit tests for a few simple/short stored procedures and functions that basically 1) test that the object exists, 2) completes expectedly with normal input, 3) completes expectedly with invalid input.
The question I have is regarding the methodology/best practice for creating unit tests for larger stored procedures. We have many procedures that are quite large with a number of steps performing many queries, with data and business validations and error handling, manipulations, etc. Here is a very basic and simplified idea of a procedure I'm describing:
create procedure foo

select userID = userIdFunction(username)

if userID is null
Select 'this is error'
return

select locationData
from Location
where 'blah'

if locationData is null
Select 'this is error'
return

select personData
from person 
where LocationData between A and C

set variables
from personData

if variables null
Select 'this is error'
return

set status 
from variables

insert data
into newTable
from personData

update existingTable
set newValues
from variables

if condition exists
then do something
else
do other thing


What could be considered the best practice for unit testing this procedure? Is it OK to simply have a unit test that confirms that it completes as expected? Or should there be tests written for specific queries/code blocks/error handling validations? Would a good approach be to create a unit test for every error handling block that validates a set of queries/operations? I understand that this is probably more of an 'art' rather than a 'science' so if there are any generic principles I could use that would help too.
Thank you!

https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-unit-testing-reference-guide-for-beginners/

@MitchWheat Thank you for the guide but what I'm looking for is well beyond the intro to tSQLt

The (somewhat unhelpful) answer is probably "it depends" - the variable factors typically being the complexity of each step in the procedure, and how critical the procedure is to the operation of your application. As complexity and application-criticality go up, the number of tests for the procedure typically also goes up.
Your example pseudocode procedure has three explicit failure states (where this is error is selected and the procedure returns early), plus a "happy path" where everything works. This probably means that you would want a minimum of four tests (one for each of the failure states and one for the happy path). However, there is also a branch in the happy-path logic with an IF statement; you might therefore need one happy path test for each branch of the IF/THEN/ELSE logic.
There are also two implicit potential failure points - either the INSERT or the UPDATE statement could fail because of a number of issues - for example a unique key violation, check constraint violation, a bad value (data type mismatch, NULL value in a non-nullable column) etc. - although you can't feasibly write tests for all the potential causes of failure, it can be helpful as a prompt to consider whether your error-handling is doing what you expect to have tests to cover failures in these statements.
Although the pseudocode example if built from simple statements, you might also choose to add tests to cover non-trivial logic - if, for example, you have complex logic to set the value of a column, or in a join condition.
Another factor to consider is the reliability of the application in its current state. If you are adding tests to an existing application which is already known to be working as expected, fewer tests might be acceptable; you could choose only to add tests to cover new functionality as you add it. By contrast, in a scenario where you are developing tests as you develop a new and as-yet unreleased application, you might choose to create more tests to verify your work as you go.
